# GOT TypeError: deprecated() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name' in boto3

Tags: python, boto3

Boto3 was running successfully the day before but when i ran today i am getting these errors
`import boto3`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/root1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/boto3/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from boto3.session import Session
  File "/home/root1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/boto3/session.py", line 17, in <module>
    import botocore.session
  File "/home/root1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 29, in <module>
    import botocore.credentials
  File "/home/root1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/credentials.py", line 35, in <module>
    from botocore.config import Config
  File "/home/root1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/config.py", line 16, in <module>
    from botocore.endpoint import DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, MAX_POOL_CONNECTIONS
  File "/home/root1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 24, in <module>
    from botocore.awsrequest import create_request_object
  File "/home/root1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 24, in <module>
    import botocore.utils
  File "/home/root1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/utils.py", line 32, in <module>
    import botocore.httpsession
  File "/home/root1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/httpsession.py", line 28, in <module>
    from urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl import orig_util_SSLContext as SSLContext
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 50, in <module>
    import OpenSSL.SSL
  File "/home/root1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import SSL, crypto
  File "/home/root1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 19, in <module>
    from OpenSSL.crypto import (
  File "/home/root1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 3224, in <module>
    utils.deprecated(
TypeError: deprecated() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'
```

i tried uninstalling and reinstalling also tried out installing specific version
still getting an error

i am using it on ubuntu 22.0
[image]

the python version i am running
`Python 3.10.6`

Comment: You haven't even provided version number of boto3 that you use, OS name and version when you run the code, is the code running on your local computer, lambda, ec2 instance , ... nor anything helpful really.

Comment: @Marcin please check i have updated it

Comment: @Neetesshhr Managed to resolve the issue?

Comment: No i reinstalled os but may be you can purge python package by `sudo apt purge python3` and reconfigure aws cli